# ArgumentError when upgrading from Ruby 2.7 -> 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to upgrade my site from Ruby 2.7 to Ruby 3.1. I updated my Gemfile to point to the new version of Ruby, ran `bundle install`, and ran `rails test` to run my test suite. I immediately got an error: `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)`. The same thing happens when I try to run `rails console`; I can't even get to the console command prompt.

I'm at a loss as to how to debug at this point, since it errors during initialization. It looks like it fails in the carrierwave-aws initialization, but I am using the most current version of that gem.

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '~> 3.1.4'

gem 'rails',                    '~> 5.2.8'
gem 'faker',                    '~> 1.6.6'
gem 'will_paginate',            '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',  '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',           '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'sass-rails',               '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',                 '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',             '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',             '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'turbolinks',               '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                 '~> 2.8'
gem 'sdoc',                     '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise',                   '~> 4.7.1'
gem 'pg',                       '~> 1.4.6'
gem 'figaro',                   '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass',        '~> 4.5.0'
gem 'morrisjs-rails',           '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'raphael-rails',            '~> 2.1.2'
gem 'redcarpet',                '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'active_record_union',      '~> 1.3.0'
gem "mini_magick",              '~> 4.12.0'
gem 'carrierwave',              '~> 2.2.3'
gem 'carrierwave-aws',          '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'business_time',            '~> 0.9.3'
gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'prawn',                    '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'responders',               '~> 2.4.1'
gem 'barby',                    '~> 0.6.6'
gem 'rqrcode',                  '~> 0.10.1'
gem 'combine_pdf',              '~> 1.0.15'

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3',     '~> 1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',      '~> 11.1.3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.3.1'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1.11'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '~> 2.4.6'
  gem 'pdf-reader',         '~> 2.2.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'seed_dump',      '3.2.4'
end
```

**Error**:

```
$ rails console
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.4/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/jmespath-1.6.2/lib/jmespath/lexer.rb:323:in `requires_wrapping?'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/jmespath-1.6.2/lib/jmespath/lexer.rb:328:in `<class:Lexer>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/jmespath-1.6.2/lib/jmespath/lexer.rb:7:in `<module:JMESPath>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/jmespath-1.6.2/lib/jmespath/lexer.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/jmespath-1.6.2/lib/jmespath.rb:9:in `<module:JMESPath>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/jmespath-1.6.2/lib/jmespath.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.171.0/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/aws-sdk-kms-1.63.0/lib/aws-sdk-kms.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.121.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/carrierwave-aws-1.5.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/aws.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/carrierwave-aws-1.5.0/lib/carrierwave-aws.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler.rb:196:in `require'
        from /vagrant/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:95:in `perform'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This might be a compatibility issue between Ruby 3.1 and Rails 5.2. [This chart](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) indicates the max version for 5.2 is 2.7. Ruby recently updated how *kwargs* (`**args`) are interpreted and this broke a lot of older Rails code.

Comment: That makes sense. I continued updating gems and got to a point where only railties and activesupport gems were involved. I will work up updating to Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

As [tadman suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065660/argumenterror-when-upgrading-from-ruby-2-7-3-1#comment134150597_76065660), the problem stemmed from the incompatibility between Ruby and Rails versions. Upgrading to Rails 6 resolved the issue.